# Detect system language change OS X

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos

Is there any way to detect the system language change event under OS X?

I've tried to search on the developer.apple.com, but with no results.

I'm looking for a solution on C++/Obj-C.

Comment: What do you mean by change? If you can detect the system language, then you should just be able to query it on start up of whatever you're making as most applications do.

Comment: By change i mean the moment, when user changing it. I want to change locale in my app "on the fly" after this event happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working in Objective-C/Swift, you can use `NSDistributedNotificationCenter` to watch for language change notifications:

```
// You are not required to register self -- this can be any object, and the selector name can be anything taking one argument.
[[NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(languageChanged:) name:@"AppleLanguagePreferencesChangedNotification" object:nil];
```

You can name `languageChanged:` whatever you'd like, as long as the method takes an `NSNotification` object:

```
- (void)languageChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    // New preferred language.
    NSString *language = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
}
```

Take a look at the [`NSDistributedNotificationCenter` docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/distributednotificationcenter) for more info.

Comment: For reference, discovering the specific notification name was relatively easy — if you register an observer for a `nil` notification name and a `nil` object, you receive _all_ notifications posted on `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`. If you log all the notifications that you get, you can just go ahead and perform the action you want (e.g. go into System Preferences and change the preferred language), then look in your log for the name.